# Числа Фибоначчи в VBA

Tags: vba, числа-фибоначчи

Написать программу вычисления числа Фибоначчи, не превосходящего заранее заданное число `N`.

Числа Фибоначчи вычисляются с помощью следующих соотношений: `F0 = 0; F1 = 1; Fi = Fi-1 + Fi-2  для i > 1`

```
Sub Main()
    Dim f1&, f2&, N&
    f1 = f2 = 1
    N = 20

    While f1 <= N
        f1 = f1 + f2
        f2 = f1 - f2
    End While
    MsgBox f2
End Sub
```

Почему-то при выполнении данного кода - *Excel* намертво зависает. Буду очень благодарен, если подскажете в чем ошибка, дабы я в будущем ее не совершал.

P.S. Могу написать данную программу на любом другом языке, но *VBA* мне что-то никак не дается.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

И как это оно у Вас работало? В *VBA* синтаксис оператора `While`

```
While condition
     [statements]
Wend
```

Но если зависает - значит, как-то удалось запустить )

Обратите внимание на строку:

```
f1 = f2 = 1
```

`f1`, `f2` - переменные типа *Long*, по умолчанию равны нулю. В переменную `f1` передается условие

```
f2 = 1 ---> 0 = 1 ---> False
```

`f1` преобразует логическое значение под себя

```
 f1 = 0
```

Из-за этого последующий цикл становится бесконечным - `f1` и `f2` не уходят из нуля.

Правильная запись

```
f1 = 1: f2 = 1
```

Ну, и дополнительный штрих

```
Const N& = 20
```